# How to set the left, top position of a TinyMCE editor?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm initializing TinyMCE on a textarea that has an absolute position (e.g. left: 100px, top:100px) but TinyMCE's is set to left: 0px, top: 0px. Unfortunately, I have not found any information on this anywhere or I have searched for the wrong terms.

```
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#myTextarea',
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    left: 100, // doesn't work.
    top: 100 // doesn't work.
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a container element, like:

```html
<div id="editor">
  <textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>
</div>
```

Now, you can position the TinyMCE editor using css:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```